# Passing parameters to subreport - missing value error

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, report, builder, subreport

I am trying to pass ID's to a subreport as they are listed in the main report. It works fine when I run it in the subreport and manually type in the ID into the parameter field but when I run it from the main report, it is giving me a "parameter is missing value" error.

Here is an example of my main report structure generated from an SQL query:

Table Structure:

Table Structure:
| Area     | 
| -------- | 
|  ID      | 
| -------- | 
| SubReport|

Example report output:
*Report generates a list of IDs and is grouped/sorted by the Area

Area: Atlanta 
\t    ID#1234 
\t\t        -Call Subreport for ID#1234 profile
\t    ID#1235
\t\t        -Call Subreport for ID#1235 profile
Area: Boston
\t    ID#1236
\t\t        -Call Subreport for ID#1236 profile

Parameter Settings in main report + subreport: (settings are identical)

A. Parameter Settings

1. It is set to visually hidden
2. Declared as a text field
3. Available + default values (not specified)

B. DataSet Properties (Parameters)

1. Parameter Name :prm_ID
2. Parameter Value [@prm_ID]

Please let me know if I can provide any more information

EDIT:
[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpU01.png)

[Current Output - The output is not how I want now, I would like to print the ID's based on the grouped Area. Its currently just printing 1 instance of the area and then printing all the records at once from the subreport since it is not accounting for the parameter. I'm not sure how to set that up. I tried using prm_ID  but have been unsuccessful in assigning it an ID for each time it call the subreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loWi3.png)

[Subreport properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrUEC.png)

Comment: Show your overall report design in design mode and also a screen grab of the subreport properties (the subreport control that is in your main report) so we can see how you are passing the values to the subreport.